# Sending mouse click events using socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, dom-events

I'm trying to emit a mouse click event from the client side to the server using socket.io and node.js. The problem is that after emitting, the dictionary I am sending is not being sent as a whole. Here's my code:

**client side:**

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(event){
 console.log("event sent", event.target,event);
 var target = event.target;
 var myClick = {id: target, event: event};
 console.log(myClick);
 socket.emit('myClick', myClick);
})

socket.on('myClick', function(data){
  console.log("event received", data);
  document.querySelectorAll(data.id).dispatchEvent(data.event);
});
```

The console logs this after a click event is registered on the body:

```
event sent <body>​…​</body>​ 
MouseEvent {isTrusted: true, screenX: 1145, screenY: 499, clientX: 1040, clientY: 398…}
Object {id: body, event: MouseEvent}
```

Other pages log this after they receive the event:

```
event received Object {id: Object, event: Object}
```

However, expanding Object gives us this:

```
event: Object
  isTrusted: true
  __proto__: Object
id: Object
  __proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

So it is not receiving the whole event and id does not have the event target.

**Server side:**

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log("socket connected");
  console.log(socket);
  socket.on('myClick', function (data) {

    console.log("myClick in server.js");
    console.log(socket);
    console.log(data);
    socket.broadcast.emit('myClick', data);
});
});
```

When the server recevies something on 'myClick' it print outs this:

```
myClick in server.js
{ id: {}, event: { isTrusted: true } }
```

As you can see, the target is empty, and what is supposed to be the full event object only has the `isTrusted` value. Has anyone faced this problem before? Any help would be appreciated. The way I was trying to do this is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499597/socket-io-mouse-click-event) Stack Overflow answer, but they were using jQuery and I am just using Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

socket.io attempts to convert the arguments you pass it to JSON.  Some things like DOM objects cannot be converted to JSON and either trigger errors or cause things to be ignored.  So, you can't send `event.target`.  It's a DOM object and you can't send a DOM object to your server.  You must send something that can be converted to a string.  For example you could send `event.target.id`.

What I would suggest you do is rather than trying to send the entire `event` object which contains many things which cannot be sent (such as DOM objects), create a new object and copy over just the properties you actually need to send.  And, make sure things you are sending do not contain DOM objects and do not contain any circular references or other things that can't be converted to JSON.

I don't know exactly which properties from the `event` object you need, but here's' the general idea:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(event){
  // create new object with just the things we need from the event object
  // this must contain only things that can be converted into JSON
  var clickData = {
     id: event.target.id, 
     timeStamp: event.timeStamp,
     type: event.type,
     clientX: event.clientX,
     clientY: event.clientY
  };
  socket.emit('myClick', clickData);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! The reason I wanted to emit the whole event is because I wanted to dispatch the same event to other pages. Do you have any suggestions on how to do that using JavaScript only? What I have on mind right now is sending the X and Y positions, and creating a new event on the receiving side and dispatching that new event.

Comment: @Faisal - Yes, you will have to capture just the relevant info about where the click was (either position or which object the click was on) and then send that info to the other clients where they can try to simulate the same action.  Just remember, you can't send DOM objects.  But, you can send identifying information (like an id) that other clients could use to know which DOM object was being referenced.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing JSON.stringify(objectYouAreSending) when you send the object, and do JSON.parse(objectYouHaveReceived) when you receive the object.

Not 100% sure on how socket.io handles objects being sent back and forth but that's the first thing I'd try. :)

Comment: I just changed my code in the listener to be:
  `var myClick = {id: target, event: event}; myClick = JSON.stringify(myClick); console.log(myClick); socket.emit('myClick', myClick);`

Sadly, console.log(myClick) prints out {"id":{},"event":{"isTrusted":true}} (this is being printed out before the object is even sent). Could it be an issue with how the dictionary is being turned into a JSON in socket.io?